# How can I keep dired in sync with a shell buffer?

Tags: dired, shell

I have some work that requires I move around between various sub-directories. Thus, the easiest way I have found to do that is to use `dired`. I also have to view some files (plain text or code), so another benefit is I can just hit `RET` on the filename to do that. However, I sometimes need to run shell commands on these files. Before I used Emacs, I would just use Bash (navigating with `pushd` and `popd`, which is less convenient than `dired`), so this allowed me to run the commands I needed.

How can I easily combine the best of both methods? I see a couple options:

1. Somehow keep a `shell` buffer in sync with the `dired` buffer. (Maybe somehow trigger `pushd`/`popd`/`cd`?)
2. Set up some keyboard shortcuts for the `shell` buffer, to simulate movement and file viewing (the latter especially seems more difficult).
3. Something else?

Note that I would prefer not to call `shell-command` (`M-!`) every time, because it is harder to execute multiple commands in quick succession, and interact with the command output, in addition to having a less-than-convenient default keybinding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify `dired-after-readin-hook` to send an appropriate command to your `shell` buffer. The following code creates a `shell` called `dired-synced-shell` if one doesn't already exist, and every time you change a directory in `dired`, runs a `cd` on the shell running in buffer `dired-synced-shell`.

```lisp
(add-hook 'dired-after-readin-hook (lambda()
                     (unless (get-buffer "dired-synced-shell") (shell "dired-synced-shell"))
                     (process-send-string (get-buffer "dired-synced-shell") (format "cd %s\n" default-directory))
                     (message "Switched to new directory")))
```

**OP Edit:** Here are two issues I found, with workarounds:

1. This doesn't work for switching to a dired buffer that already exists. Workaround: press `g` to refresh the buffer.
2. This causes my shell prompt to get smashed together with the previous, as it might if the output of the previous command didn't contain a newline. (E.g. if my shell prompt is `[scott@local]$`, then on switching to a new dired buffer, I would see `[scott@local]$ [scott@local]$`. Workaround: add a newline to the beginning of my shell prompt.